# Use MomentJs with not ISO standard date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I have an array with data formats from which I need to add days to specific date formatted with some of this array.

This is the array with possible formats:

```
        'yy-mm-dd',
        'yy-dd-mm',
        'dd-mm-yy',
        'mm-dd-yy',
        'dd-yy-mm',
        'mm-yy-dd',
```

I have a function with arguments: `fromDate`, `months` - (30 days * months) to be added and a boolean for converting to some of these formats in the array or just using standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```
function calc_end_date(fromdate, months, convertFormat) {
    var days = 30 * months;

    if (convertFormat) {
        return moment(new Date(fromdate), custom_vars.current_date_format).add(days, 'd');
    } else {
        return moment(fromdate).add(days, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }


    return null;
}
```

The code knows which format will be used with: `custom_vars.current_date_format`.
The current format that I am using now is `dd-yy-mm` and I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined

I have tried everything and I am getting above error or depreciation warning for non standard ISO format and invalid date.

Comment: Use the `moment()` constructor that allows you to explicitly specify a date format, and pass the string, not a `new Date()` constructed from the string; that defeats the whole purpose of using Moment.

Comment: `new Date()` removes the warning for the ISO format.

Comment: Well Moment can handle standard ISO dates too; none of the formats in the list you posted are ISO 8601 formats because the year must be 4 digits.